# Excel: Textjoin skip header if cell is blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I want to use textjoin. My formula right now works until it finds a blank cell, the Header is still joined.

What I like to have is that when a cell is empty, the header is ignored.

My formula until now is this, yet I don't know how to proceed further.

```
=TEKST.JOIN(" + ",TRUE,$A$2:$O$2&", "&A3:O3)

The desired outcome row 2 to 4:

Material+VZ
Driver+SW-12

And for row 5:

Material+VZ
Model+X4
Drive+SW-12
```

Hoping someone can help me on the way.

I have tried searching stackoverflow, and approaching the formula on a different way

Comment: Use FILTER to filter out the blanks and only return the ones with values.

Comment: Hi Scott, how can i apply this in the formula? thx for reacting

Comment: Would you provide the expected output for the input of your question. It is not clear to me what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi David i have edited my question with the expected outcome

Comment: Would you clarify what goes on each row of the output, the way you put it is not clear to me. Provide at least the screenshot of the expected output, so I can understand the content of each row. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want, put in cell `E2` the following formula:

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",,MAP(A2:A5, B2:B5, C2:C5, LAMBDA(a,b,c, 
 IF(a<>"", A1&"+"&a&",", "") & IF(b<>"", B1&"+"&b&",", "") 
   & IF(c<>"", C1&"+"&c&",", "")))),,",",1)
```

You can encapsulate the `IF` logic in a user `LAMBDA` function (`ADD`) as follow:

```
=LET(ADD, LAMBDA(title, x, IF(x<>"", title &"+"& x &",", "")),
 TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("",,MAP(A2:A5, B2:B5, C2:C5, LAMBDA(a,b,c, ADD(A1,a) &
  ADD(B1,b) & ADD(C1,c)))),,",",1))
```

Here is the output:

[image: excel output]